# Access same variable from 2 or more class

Tags: java

Here is my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    java.util.ArrayList data_queue=new java.util.ArrayList();
    Producer p = new Producer(data_queue);
    Consumer c = new Consumer(data_queue);
    p.start();
    c.start();
    System.out.println(“Random Week Day:”);
}

class Producer extends Thread{
    ArrayList data_queue;
    public Producer(ArrayList data_queue){
        this.data_queue=data_queue;
    }
    public void run(){
        //your code; Create random week day, Add
    }
}

class Consumer extends Thread{
    ArrayList data_queue;
    public Consumer(ArrayList data_queue){
        this.data_queue=data_queue;
    }
    public void run(){
        //your code: Remove, display
    }
}
```

Producer Create random weekday and add to ArrayList at last -> and print
Consumer get the first element in this ArrayList -> delete it -> and print

If I cannot edit anything at MAIN FUNCTION, just only change at Producer and Consumer. How can I access to the same variable (ArrayList data_queue) to ADD and DELETE by Thread

Comment: Why not use a synchronized method?

Comment: Why would accessing the array list be a problem? The arraylist which is instantiated in the main method is passed to the constructors of both the Consumer and the Producer class, and is available as an instance variable in those classes...

Comment: For real production code, consider using a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) instead.

Comment: @JtheRocker In fact, just synchronizing on the data_queue probably wouldn't be enough. If you do that, there is no guarantee that the Consumer thread does not acquire the lock before the Producer thread.

Comment: @Alderath, I know that. Just was a initial suggestion. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that your teacher wants you to use `data_queue.wait()` and `data_queue.notifyAll()`. The consumer should wait while the queue is empty, and the producer should notify each time it puts an element in the queue.

Read the javadoc of those methods (in java.lang.Object) carefully, because they're hard-to-use, low-level synchronization mechanisms. The [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) is also a good reference.

Comment: My brother have an excercise and his teacher want using this MAIN FUNCTION and DONT BE CHANGE this. I just change code at Producer and Consumer but cannot sync value of ArrayList if NOT CHANGE main func. The result always: Added: Friday
Random Weekday: 
Deleted: Friday
Added: Wednesday
Added: Saturday
Added: Thursday
Added: Monday

Comment: First of all, I'm not your brother. Second, no need to shout. Third, where did I tell you to modify anything in the main method? Why couldn't you synchronize on the list from the consumer's run method and the producer's run method? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

You're already accessing the same object. You only called `new` once and so there's only one ArrayList which you have passed to everyone. Don't forget to take care about synchronization between threads like:

```
List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
```